# Access Database Using Integrated ASP.Net MVC4 Membership

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

When I create MVC4 Internet Project I use the integrated membership which is already written in AccountController. When user is registered he goes to database which is connected with the default connection string `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AccountPortal-20131128183241;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AccountPortal-20131128183241.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`.

How to access and make queries to this database. If I want to use ASP.Net Configuration Tool it gives me the following message when I click Security.

If I want to manipulate this database how to access it ?

**There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.**

**The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.**

In Web.config I have the following connection string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AccountPortal-20131128183241;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AccountPortal-20131128183241.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="AccountDataModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/AccountDataModel.csdl|res://*/AccountDataModel.ssdl|res://*/AccountDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=OWNER-PC;initial catalog=AccountPortal;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `AttachDBFilename` is deprecated

Comment: So what is the alternative way ?

Comment: Don't use `AttachDBFilename`

Comment: How to create the tables which this membership uses and to create connection string to it ?

Comment: Last time I checked it created the tables for you. I assume you have LocalDB installed. Try `Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;`

Comment: It creates App_Data folder automatically. If I change with this data source which you gave to me it will create there the tables ?

Comment: I haven't done this in a while. Try it and see.

Comment: With <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=OWNER-PC;Initial Catalog=AccountPortal;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MembershipTest-20131202111852.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> It gives the following error:

Comment: Database 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AccountPortal.mdf' already exists. Choose a different database name.
Cannot attach the file 'c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MembershipTest\MembershipTest\App_Data\aspnet-MembershipTest-20131202111852.mdf' as database 'AccountPortal'.

Comment: Can you test it and see please ?

Comment: You're still using `AttachDBFilename`.

Comment: But I changed the connection string. Where else should I change it ?